# Why is Scipy.linalg.eigh much slower when using np.complex64?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, blas, eigenvector

I have a large Hermitian matrix of which I need to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. For this I use `scipy.linalg.eigh`. Above a certain size of the matrix, scipy is much faster if `np.complex128` is used as data type instead of `np.complex64`.

If I use `np.complex64`, the CPU load drops after some time and only one core is used. I checked the SciPy source and SciPy seems to use the `cheevr` or `zheevr` methods from lapack. I use SciPy with openblas-0.3.20. Is this a bug in openblas?

If I run the following code with 32 cores, it takes about 13 minutes with `np.complex128` but more than 2 hours with `np.complex64`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
import time

n = 27 
shape = (n**3, n**3)
dtype = np.complex64

H = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, shape) + 1.j * np.random.uniform(-1, 1, shape)
H = np.asarray(H, dtype=dtype)
start = time.time()
values, vectors = scipy.linalg.eigh(H)
print(f"It took {time.time() - start} seconds.")
```

Comment: I can't really reproduce a test case with such a long runtime but just in case it affects the performance: Your input matrix is not hermitian. Try changing your matrix to something like ```H = H @ H.conj().T``` or at the very least, set the imaginary part of the main diagonal to 0. As for the main issue, I suspect it simply doesn't converge due to rounding errors or lack of value range. Did you try the ```driver``` argument to see if one works better?

Comment: @Homer512 Yes, the matrix is not Hermitian but SciPy will just use the lower diagonal and work on that. So it should not make a difference. I will check out different `driver`s now. Thanks.

Comment: It will just use the lower triangle but I wouldn't count on it ignoring the imaginary part of the diagonal. In any case, ```driver='evd'``` seems to help.